# Bs4 returning an AttributeError for any site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I think my problem mainly stems from my computer. My code idea is to make a search engine based off google. My code worked for a while, but then I share it to other people and the code on my pc would recieve the error, but their copy of the code would. I have no idea why this is happening.

The error is: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'`

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

search = input("Enter the query: ")
link = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search.replace(' ', '+')}&safe=active"
hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }

req = urllib.request.Request(link, headers=hdr)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

print(soup.find('div', id='rcnt').prettify())
```

I have also tried bs4 on other sites for other projects, but I would still get the error.

Comment: `"the code on my pc wouldn't work"`, `"still get the error"` -- *what* error? "doesn't work" is a pretty vague problem description. [edit] and include them in your question so we can better help you.

Comment: so it's not for any site but just for google?

Comment: @diggusbickus No, it doesn't work for any site.

Comment: that is because soup.find found nothing with those criteria of `'div', id='rcnt'`, when nothing is found it return nothing, aka None, hence the error...

Comment: @Copperfield Yes, I know that. I just don't understand how my code would work flawlessly before and then give me the error.

Comment: that sample code doesn't work for me either, therefore you search criteria for `find` is wrong somehow and need to be refined, if it worked before then maybe google change thing on their end somehow

Comment: I did a quick query and captured the html output. There are divs, but there is no id='rcnt'.  You need to review your output and check for the proper *id* or whatever other factor you're searching for. I will post what I did as an Answer.

Comment: Google could change HTML and now it may not have `id='rcnt'`. OR it may send HTML with different values for different users in different moments and different devices - all to block bots and scripts - because Google earns BIG money on displaying `ads` on this page and your script/bot will not click in ads. Google may have very complex system to detect bots so scraping Google can be hard task. BTW: Google has also API for some services for developers/codes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to take another look at your output from Google. The below code will grab the output and store it as a file that you can review.
From what I see, your code works until it tries to find a match for `id='rcnt'`. The match returns None, so the call to prettify fails, giving you the error you see.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

search = input("Enter the query: ")
link = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search.replace(' ', '+')}&safe=active"
hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }

req = urllib.request.Request(link, headers=hdr)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
if response.msg == "OK":
    open('soup.html', "wb").write(soup.text.encode('utf-8'))
divs = soup.find_all('div')
print(len(divs))
print(soup.find('div', id='rcnt'))
```